# Google Web App: Can't read or write on my label after evaluate the page

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I have a label on my HTML page which shows number returned values. I can't read or change that when it is loaded? but locally I can do that with a console log.

```
<p name= 'message' id='ftext' > This team have 
  <label id="teams" > <?= teamSize ?> </label>
  members.  </p>
```

it returns `null` for both of these tag ids `document.getElementById('team')` or `document.getElementById('ftext')`, so I can't get their innerText or text Contents. 
I am using `HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile(file).evaluate()` for rendering the page.
here is a link to my project: [Attendance Form](https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycby0NAdkQrEFIF5PXj4hZUtBHCtfa-vG6sbTmaqlW_iddLJFe2_F/exec?v=form&id=33&t=70035%20(Wing%2038))

Thanks for your help,
M

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said that document.getElementById('team') didn't work, but you actually named your id "teams".

If that fix doesn't work, can you share your code?

It's really frustrating to get variables between the frontend and the backend in GAS!

Something like this:

```
  google.script.run
  .withSuccessHandler(finishedOutput)
  .withFailureHandler(errorOutput)
  .split(); // SPLIT IS THE GS SCRIPT THAT PASSES BACK THE NUMBER YOU WANT
```

and then this

```
  function finishedOutput(info) //INFO IS THE THING THAT GOT PASSED BACK BEFORE
  {
    var br='<br />';
    var outputDiv = document.getElementById('status');
    outputDiv.innerHTML = 'The spreadsheet has been split.' + br +'New files in this folder: ' + info.link + br ;
    document.getElementById('process').style.display="none";

  };
```

In my example I was passing back an object that had a info key but you can do this with a number or a string rather than an object.

these are both inside  on the html page, and then the "split" function is on Code.gs and is a GAS function. Messy, right?

Comment: No the issue is not the synax or typo. I tried different ids. Here is a link to my app: https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycby0NAdkQrEFIF5PXj4hZUtBHCtfa-vG6sbTmaqlW_iddLJFe2_F/exec?v=form&id=33&t=70035%20(Wing%2038)
I will also update my OP

Comment: As I checked, it seems because of sandbox IFrame thing of GAS, it is not possible to access documents elements by id and so from the browser, but it works inside page JavaScript itself!

Comment: yes, you run javascript in the front end portions that are passed values from the gas backend. To get at backend GAS you do something like I'm goign to edit my above comment so I can format it as code

Comment: Actually, I am aware of passing element between front end and back end in GAS. My problem at first was I didn't know I can't use console log in client side to get my elements as I identified them, which was because of the sand boxing things. but no matter, still I have cases I can't reach my html elements by ID inside my java script section of same page. It worked on a test page I built, but not working some other places. It is really confusing yet.